# Adding http request headers in NGINX

Tags: http, nginx, cloud-foundry

Is there any way to add in request header while sending it to proxy server? I tried using `add_header` as well as `proxy_set_header` but it did not work for me.

Below is the headers.conf file content I tried:

Trial1:

```
proxy_set_header X-Name "Vishal";
```

Trial2:

```
add_header X-Name "Vishal";
```

My nginx\conf\includes\proxy.conf:

```
location /api/mysvc/v1 {

        proxy_pass "https://mockable.io/mysvc/v1/";
        proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
        proxy_set_header X-Name "Vishal";

}
```

I want to pass along this request header in every ajax request my app makes.

Comment: `proxy_set_header` is the correct directive to use. Where is `headers.conf` included? What does the block containing the `proxy_pass` statement look like?

Comment: @RichardSmith updated answer

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: @RichardSmith just realised I should not add the proxy_set_header in my headers.conf file. Had to keep only in proxy.conf file for it to work. More so, these headers are not logged in browser debugging tool. Thanks much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just realised I should not add the proxy_set_header in my headers.conf file. Had to keep only in proxy.conf file for it to work. More so, these headers are not logged in browser debugging tool.